# ClassNotFoundException when setting hive.exec.pre.hooks

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hook

I am following this document to do hive hook:

http://dharmeshkakadia.github.io/hive-hook/

But I got this error when `show tables`

```
2018-08-12 09:57:38,122 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-315]: hive.exec.pre.hooks Class not found: HiveExampleHook
2018-08-12 09:57:38,122 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-315]: FAILED: Hive Internal Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException(HiveExampleHook)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HiveExampleHook
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.HooksLoader.getHooks(HooksLoader.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.HooksLoader.getHooks(HooksLoader.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1280)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:236)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$300(SQLOperation.java:89)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$3$1.run(SQLOperation.java:301)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$3.run(SQLOperation.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2018-08-12 09:57:38,122 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-315]: </PERFLOG method=Driver.execute start=1534067858120 end=1534067858122 duration=2 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2018-08-12 09:57:38,122 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-315]: Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20180812095757_e6516d83-ddc9-4f82-8151-def7e7f1eb37); Time taken: 0.002 seconds
2018-08-12 09:57:38,122 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-315]: <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2018-08-12 09:57:38,122 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-315]: </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1534067858122 end=1534067858122 duration=0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2018-08-12 09:57:38,130 ERROR org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-315]: Error running hive query:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Hive Internal Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException(HiveExampleHook)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:400)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:238)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$300(SQLOperation.java:89)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$3$1.run(SQLOperation.java:301)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$3.run(SQLOperation.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HiveExampleHook
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.HooksLoader.getHooks(HooksLoader.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.HooksLoader.getHooks(HooksLoader.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1280)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:236)
    ... 11 more
```

I am sure the last step `add jar target/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar;` is wrong.

I tried the following:

1. I put the jar file into hdfs /user/hive/ :

   add jar hdfs:///user/hive/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar;
2. I also set "Hive Auxiliary JARs Directory" as 
   /home/centos/HiveExampleHook/target/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar in Hiveserver2 node and restart Hive plus beeline.
3. Copy the jar file to `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/`
4. Copy the jar file to `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/`

Nothing helps.

Any idea?

**UPDATE 1:**

If I do `LIST JARS;` this would show

```
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
|                      resource                      |
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
| /tmp/3fe67bb1-5cfd-427f-8faa-cab6524afeb3_resources/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar |
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
```

I tried two ways to do `CREATE FUNCTION` too:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION test1 AS 'HiveExampleHook';
INFO  : Compiling command(queryId=hive_20180812153838_47589f9d-eaeb-410d-80b0-9cf414ae557f): CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION test1 AS 'HiveExampleHook'
INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed
INFO  : Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:null, properties:null)
INFO  : Completed compiling command(queryId=hive_20180812153838_47589f9d-eaeb-410d-80b0-9cf414ae557f); Time taken: 0.002 seconds
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hive_20180812153838_47589f9d-eaeb-410d-80b0-9cf414ae557f): CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION test1 AS 'HiveExampleHook'
INFO  : Starting task [Stage-0:FUNC] in serial mode
ERROR : FAILED: Class HiveExampleHook not found
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20180812153838_47589f9d-eaeb-410d-80b0-9cf414ae557f); Time taken: 0.003 seconds
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask (state=08S01,code=1)
```

and...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION test1 AS 'HiveExampleHook' USING JAR 'hdfs:///user/hive/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar';
INFO  : Compiling command(queryId=hive_20180812153939_cf1f31c9-0361-47dc-8903-78221bd12401): CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION test1 AS 'HiveExampleHook' USING JAR 'hdfs:///user/hive/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar'
INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed
INFO  : Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:null, properties:null)
INFO  : Completed compiling command(queryId=hive_20180812153939_cf1f31c9-0361-47dc-8903-78221bd12401); Time taken: 0.004 seconds
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=hive_20180812153939_cf1f31c9-0361-47dc-8903-78221bd12401): CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION test1 AS 'HiveExampleHook' USING JAR 'hdfs:///user/hive/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar'
INFO  : Starting task [Stage-0:FUNC] in serial mode
INFO  : converting to local hdfs:///user/hive/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar
INFO  : Added [/tmp/3fe67bb1-5cfd-427f-8faa-cab6524afeb3_resources/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar] to class path
INFO  : Added resources: [hdfs:///user/hive/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar]
ERROR : FAILED: Class HiveExampleHook not found
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20180812153939_cf1f31c9-0361-47dc-8903-78221bd12401); Time taken: 0.03 seconds
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask (state=08S01,code=1)
```

So clearly it can find the jar but not the class name. Am I right?

**UPDATE 2:**

I tried this:

```
[Hive-hook-example]# java -cp `pwd`/target/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar HiveExampleHook
```

And still got this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HiveExampleHook
```

I believe this is some stupid mistake I did.

**UPDATE 3:**

OK I got it figured out. **You have to use hive CLI and not beeline for this to work.**

```
hive> add jar hdfs:///user/hive/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar;
add jar hdfs:///user/hive/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar
converting to local hdfs:///user/hive/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar
Added [/tmp/0a90132d-70cd-4ef0-b4cd-e75dc823e5ca_resources/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar] to class path
Added resources: [hdfs:///user/hive/Hive-hook-example-1.0.jar]
hive> set hive.exec.pre.hooks=HiveExampleHook;
set hive.exec.pre.hooks=HiveExampleHook
hive> show tables;
show tables
Hello from the hook !!
OK
test1
Time taken: 0.023 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

So the question is how to run this in beeline then? Because hive CLI is deprecated.

**UPDATE 4:**

I decided to do this:
[image]

Ran `beeline` and saw this:

```
2018-08-12 16:39:13,286 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-60]: <PERFLOG method=PreHook.HiveExampleHook from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2018-08-12 16:39:13,286 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log.PerfLogger: [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-60]: </PERFLOG method=PreHook.HiveExampleHook start=1534091953286 end=1534091953286 duration=0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2
```

That is some progress although I am not sure what it means and whether the class was ran. As I see nothing output.

Comment: FWIW... I vaguely remember swearing aloud about the (poorly documented) differences between `add jar` and `add jars` a few years ago.

Answer (score 2):

With beeline, you have to use HDFS path while adding jar. Remember beeline is just a JDBC CLI, so when you use add jar with local path, it has the reference to you local path, that is not accessible to hive session running on the cluster.

(Thanks for asking https://twitter.com/quanghoc/status/1028671393376874496 for help. I am the author of the blog you referred to.)

Comment: I used hdfs path. But it doesn't work on beeline and only works on Hive CLI. Why is that? Please see my updates.

Comment: Which update did you use HDFS path with beeline ? sorry its bit confusing with many updates.

Comment: My original UPDATE 0 used hdfs path. I never used local path.

Comment: I think it might have been messed up with you setting a local Aux jar path. Just have jar on HDFS, run add jar, see it with list jar to check.

Comment: The jar is in HDFS. So should I empty Aux jar path?

Comment: Aux jars path just means that it will be implicitly added to your class path. No need if you are explicitly adding jars.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. I have both the jar in local and hdfs. I added via hdfs. But regardless, hive CLI works. Beeline shows some effect in **UPDATE 4** which I am not sure. Thought?

Comment: Its hard to debug this remotely. I am super sure that add jar with HDFS works. Two suggestions:
1. If you can live with hive CLI, do it.
2. Put your jar where the original aux jar path was pointing (on the HDFS).

Comment: I suspect `System.out.println("Hello from the hook !!");` doesn't print out via beeline. Is that right?

Comment: It does. The output would be in hiveserver2 logs. Beeline is just a client for a session running on the cluster. The session is managed by hiveserver2.

Comment: I checked using `hive -hiveconf hive.log.file=debug_hive_1.log -hiveconf hive.log.dir=/tmp/hivedebug/  -hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,DRFA` and the output never showed in the log file for hive CLI either. But it shows in the hive CLI console screen. This is Cloudera 5.14.0 so...